# Banner in middle of navigation is clipped inside for Internet Explorer?

Tags: html, css, navigation

This was my first time attempting to code a banner in the middle of the navigation, and unfortunately it did not work out so well. I am clueless of what I should do, for I tried overflow but it did not seem to work.

HTML:

```
<nav>
<ul>
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Register</a></li>
    <li><a href="">About</a></li>
    <li class="logo"><a href="#"></a></li>
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Register</a></li>
    <li><a href="">About</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Style:

```
nav ul {
width: auto;
height: 74px;
position: relative;
z-index: 5;
overflow: visible;
}

nav ul li {
list-style-type: none;
float: left;
display: inline-block;
padding: 0px 30px;
width: auto;
height: 74px;
}

nav ul li.logo {
background: url(logo.png) no-repeat; 
width: 200px; 
height: 175px; 
position: relative;
top: -83px;
left: 5px;
}
```

[image: Example of how in Internet Explorer the banner in the middle is not overflowing.]

So as you can see, the banner is bigger than the height of the navigation itself, and it appears fine on browsers like Chrome, Firefox and Opera. However, on Internet Explorers, the banner appears clipped inside and it's not overflowing. I tried overflow properties but they don't seem to work. What should I do?

Comment: Can you provide all of the CSS that you're using?  What you've given here doesn't look anything like either of those images.

Comment: Also, which version of internet explorer are you using?  The <nav> tag isn't supported in anything under IE9.

Comment: Hello. It did not work with Internet Explorer 9 either. Chris I know I basically restarted the CSS coding and it does not look that great, which is why I only gave you those. Could you be able to do js fiddle and see if you can figure it out? I would greatly greatly appreciate that!

Comment: Why don't you set up a fiddle?